# Argparse can't be typed in from command prompt

Tags: python, argparse

I have trouble with my code here. I can't seem to make the argparse arguments work. Ideally, the code should run, and I should be able to parse in the arguments from command prompt. If you run the script it prints 
Namespace(c=False, d=False, f=False, path='.', s=False)
How do I write it so that the code executes properly?

```
import os
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', help='counts the number of files in folder', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-d', help='returns a dictionary as filename: {}, filesize: {}', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-f', help='returns a dictionary which contains foldername, size of the folder and subfiles', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-s', help='gives the total number of bytes in folder and subfolders', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-path', metavar='<path to folder>', default='.', help='path for counting')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
counter = 0
size = 0
dict = {'.': 0}

for parent, dirnames, files in os.walk(args.path):
    for filenames in files:
        if args.s:
            size += s
            print("Total bytes: ", size)
        if args.d:
            print(filename, s, 'b')
        if args.f:
            if parent in dict:
                dict[parent] += s
            else:
                dict[parent] = s
        if args.c:
            count += 1
            print("Number of files: ", counter)
        if args.f:
            for files in dict:
                print(files, dict.get(files), 'b')
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know why argparse isn't working? Like is the argparse package already installed?

Comment: What's `s` in your script ? have you defined it ?

Comment: I actually forgot about defining s... I defined it as

Comment: What arguments do you provide at the "command prompt".  The printed `Namespece` is shows the default values, suggesting that you didn't provide any command line values.  How are you calling this script?  Do you know what `command line` values are, or how to provide them?

Comment: And if all the `args` attributes are `False`, none of those `if` statements will be executed.  What did you expect?